# What does "using join buffer" means in the Explain table of an MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following complex query and I notice that it is making my website so slow I want to find a way to optimize it:

```
SELECT tahminler.result,
tahminler.tahmin,
tahminler.match_id, 
tahminler.timestamp, 
tahminler.tahmin_text, 
users.username, 
matches_of_comments.tournament_id,
matches_of_comments.match_status,
matches_of_comments.match_date,
matches_of_comments.localteam_name,
matches_of_comments.visitorteam_name,
matches_of_comments.localteam_id,
matches_of_comments.visitorteam_id,
matches_of_comments.localteam_goals,
matches_of_comments.visitorteam_goals,
new_iddaa.iddaa_code, 
tahminler_results.ms1, 
tahminler_results.ms2, 
tahminler_results.ms0, 
tahminler_results.alt, 
tahminler_results.ust, 
tahminler_results.tg_0_1, 
tahminler_results.tg_2_3, 
tahminler_results.tg_4_6, 
tahminler_results.tg_7, 
tahminler_results.kg_var, 
tahminler_results.kg_yok, 
tahmins.tahmin as text_tahmin 
FROM tahminler 
INNER JOIN users on users.id = tahminler.user_id 
INNER JOIN matches_of_comments on tahminler.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id 
Left JOIN new_iddaa on new_iddaa.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id 
INNER JOIN tahmins on tahminler.tahmin = tahmins.id 
LEFT JOIN tahminler_results on tahminler.match_id = tahminler_results.match_id 
Where tahminler.user_id = $user_id 
order by tahminler.timestamp DESC
```

I do not have much experience in databases or optimization so I did an Explain for this query and i got this table :

[image: explain table]

I think the problem in the row which tells "using join buffer" but what does that mean ??
can you help me to understand this point and making the query optimized ?

Comment: [Using join buffer:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types)
Tables from earlier joins are read in portions into the join buffer, and then their rows are used from the buffer to perform the join with the current table. Read about [Top 20 mysql best practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/)

Comment: and how to do a join buffer in my query?

Comment: @Damodaran, that "mysql best practices" article is pretty dated, and several of its recommendations were wrong even when it was written.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking for indices, especially on the columns you want to join on. Do you have an index on matches_of_comments.match_id? Also, an index on tahmins.id seems to be missing.